# Calculable. Expresiones con condicionales

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando calcular una formula con java pero cuando intento usar un condicional, para que haga una cosa u otra según si un parámetro es verdadero o falso. Añado método.

```
public void calcular (){
    Calculable calc = null;
    try {
        calc = new ExpressionBuilder("(4-2)/100").build();
    } catch (UnknownFunctionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnparsableExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    double result1=calc.calculate();
}
```

Esto funciona perfecto pero cuando intento ponerle algo así en la expresión no funciona:

```
(30>20 ? 3+2 : (4-2)/100); //esto por ejemplo.
```

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Ese condicional, si no me equivoco, lo tienes que poner fuera, no se permite poner un condicional dentro de una expresión para evaluar

Comment: No falta un paréntesis? `new ExpressionBuilder("(4-2)/100")`

Comment: Corregido. si faltaba. De todas formas no es esa expresion la que falla. Esa funciona bien. La que no me funciona es (30>20 ? 3+2 : (4-2)/100); 
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la librería que usas?  `net.objecthunter.exp4j`?

Comment: Hola. Si, es esa librería

Comment: Pero me parece que estás usando una versión antigua, la nueva ya no tiene el método calculate() ni la interfaz Calculable, puedes verlo [aquí](https://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/#Version_0.4.0_API_Changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumo el uso de la librería https://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j en la versión 0.4.X:

El problema es que entre [los operadores por defecto de esa biblioteca no se encuentra el operador ternario ni el operador *mayor que*](https://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/#Built-in_operators)

La solución sería añadir tú esos operadores, pero el siguiente problema es que la librería limita el número de parámetros para un operador a 1 o 2... que lo puedes solucionar definiendo una función en lugar de un operador, que no tiene esas limitaciones:

```
Function ternario = new Function("ternary", 3) {
    @Override
    public double apply(double... args) {
        //limitacion: no hay booleans, 0 será false y >0 sera true
        if (args[0]>0d) {
            return args[1];
        }
        return args[2];
    }
};


Operator mayorQue = new Operator(">", 2, true, Operator.PRECEDENCE_ADDITION - 1) {

    @Override
    public double apply(double[] values) {
        if (values[0] > values[1]) {
            return 1d;
        } else {
            return 0d;
        }
    }
};
```

Con lo que tu código podría ser algo como

```
double resultado=new ExpressionBuilder("ternary(30>20,3+2,(4-2)/100)")
    .operator(mayorQue)
    .function(ternario)
    .build().evaluate();
```

Finalmente, en caso de necesidad, podrías tú procesar el String recibido con el operador ternario clásico `cond ? resultado1 : resultado2` y transformarlo a `ternary(cond,resultado1,resultado2)`, pero eso queda ya fuera del ámbito de la pregunta.

Comment: Genial, ha funcionado aunque tuve que usar CustomFunction y CustomOperator ya que ExpresionBuilder solo aceptaba: .withOpetarion(CustomOperator) y .withCustomFunction(CustomFunction). Pero es similar. Muchas gracias, ha funcionado.

Comment: Pues si te ha ayudado, @mabts,  puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada con el `✓` que tiene al lado, así queda la pregunta marcada como respondida